# JavaFX and Sockets = Not on FX application thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, javafx

I need to wait for a Server program to send data to the Client program using a socket so I must wait for it using a while loop. However the Client program is a JavaFX Application and if used in a while loop it will freeze up and crash so I put the while loop in a new Thread. However the body of this while loop needs to update the JavaFX UI which cannot be done as it causes "Not on FX application thread;" Exception so I cannot create a new thread for it.

This is my code:

```
import static util.Constants.PORT;
import static util.Constants.SERVER_NAME;

public class Client extends Application {

    private static View view;
    public static Scanner in;
    public static PrintWriter out;
    private static boolean appRunning = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_NAME, PORT);
            in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            launch(args);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not establish connection to server. Program terminating..");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
        // This is a JavaFX BorderPane that adds itself to window:
        view = new View(window);

        // ServerListener
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (appRunning) {
                    // will through exception. needs to run on Application thread:
                    parseServerMessage(Client.in.nextLine()); 
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private static String[] parseServerMessage(String message0 { 
        // update the JavaFX UI
    }
}
```

and if I used this code below in the start method without the thread, the JavaFX app will freeze:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
    // This is a JavaFX BorderPane that adds itself to window:
    view = new View(window);

    // causes JavaFX to freeze:
    while (appRunning) {            
        parseServerMessage(Client.in.nextLine()); 
    }
}
```

Also putting the thread to sleep doesn't help.
How can I get around this problem? Thank you!

EDIT Solution:

Thanks to the solution, I edited my code and now it works perfectly. Here is the edited solution:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        String serverMessage = Client.in.nextLine();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
             parseServerMessage(serverMessage);                  
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Not sure because I am still learning how to use Threads. I will try looking into that, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) which provides the same functionality as a thread, but in a more elegant way. It has methods using which you can use to directly update the JavaFX UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [Platform::runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-). From the JavaDoc:

> Run the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some unspecified time in the future. This method, which may be called from any thread, will post the Runnable to an event queue and then return immediately to the caller.

Comment: Thanks, so if I created an "updateUI" method in the Client JavaFX Application class, how can I get runLater to run that one method? Examples I have seen using this create a whole new Runnable which wouldn't work for my case.

Comment: Never mind I did it! :D Thanks that worked perfectly!